# TextView set image on last line

Tags: java, android, textview

Is there any way to place the image on the last line of the TextView

I use  `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds`. Some ideas about it will be good.

Also i need to handle clicks on my image only. This behavior is represented by the following code :

```
   textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.info, 0);
                textView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                            if(event.getRawX() >= textView.getRight() - textView.getTotalPaddingRight()){

                                listener.onAddressClicked(livingAreas);

                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: last line of text view ? So basically are you trying to put the image at the bottom of text view ?

Comment: @Lokesh I have already tried to use `RelativeLayout` with TextView + ImageView but no success.

Comment: You can use android:drawable property in TextView.

Comment: Try to change relativeLayout to LinearLayout with vertical orientation. I think this will solve your question. Also dont forget about some parameters in textView and image view for best solution.

Comment: Why you can't just put an image to ImageView below your TextView?

Comment: Look at this also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32063821/1159507

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Text view you can set a drawable on a determinated position.

You can use this xml example:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableBottom="@drawable/image"
    android:text="blablabla"/>
```

Programmatically:

> `public void setCompoundDrawables(Drawable left, Drawable top, Drawable right, Drawable bottom)`

```
text_view.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, null, getDrawable(drawable_image_id));
```

Comment: How to set that position?

Comment: From API: public void setCompoundDrawables(Drawable left, Drawable top, Drawable right, Drawable bottom)

Answer (score 1):

Use `SpannableString` so that you can include image in your text. For code sample, check [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31969409/5137352)